# Accessing Constants Static Class That References App Settings Config File

Tags: c#

I have a class called LocalConstants....

```
 public static class LocalConstants {
    public static string DM_PATH = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DMQueue"];
    public static string PROJECT_PATH = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MSQueue"];
 }
```

When trying to access this class in my main program I am getting a null reference exception. Anything from ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[ is always null. But if I write

```
  //The value is returned fine 
  string bo=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MSQueue"];
```

this compiles fine but is always null and throws a NullRefexception

```
   string moomoo = LocalConstants.PROJECT_PATH;
```

The exception is
The type initializer for 'TestCodeOutOnSide.LocalConstants' threw an exception.

The innerException is the basic
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Even if I change the PROJECT_PATH to

```
public static readonly string PROJECT_PATH = @"FORMATNAME:DIRECT=OS:serus-nickl\RMQDEV";
```

I get the same exception

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `LocalConstants` in the same project as the app.config?

Comment: Yes everything is in the same project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called this

```
public static string Environment = AppEnvironmentVariable.ToUpper() != "PROD" ? "***FROM " + AppEnvironmentVariable.ToUpper() + "** " : "";
```

Before this

```
public static string AppEnvironmentVariable = "DEV";
```

In the LocalConstants file which broke it because of what Josh said about  Static field initialization

Answer (score 5):

To begin with, if you are doing this to provide some sort of performance benefit then you should know that these are cached. See [ConfigurationManager.AppSettings Caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389361/configurationmanager-appsettings-caching-doubt), to remove any.

Second the issue is most likely that [Static field initialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645758%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) does not work how you expect it to. So your code as written provides no guarantee of that  `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` has been run.  From the linked article sample code:

> might produce either the output:

```
Init A
Init B
1 1
```

> or the output:

```
Init B
Init A
1 1
```

[EDIT per OP comment]

There must be something else involved as:

```
public static class LocalConstants
{
    public static string DM_PATH = "DMQueue";
    public static string PROJECT_PATH = "MSQueue";
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string moomoo = LocalConstants.PROJECT_PATH;

        Console.WriteLine(moomoo);
    }
}
```

works for me.

[Edit 2 - Fro those who come after]

It looks like [The type initializer for ‘SomeClass’ threw an exception](http://blog.wouldbetheologian.com/2009/03/type-initializer-for-someclass-threw.html) can be a case where

> But when it's called by the WPF designer, the "application" is Visual Studio, which (presumably) doesn't have the appropriate connection strings in its .config file;

The fix for that author was:

> moving the instantiation of my Entity Data Model into a property

Comment: Any suggestions on a better way to approach this?

Comment: @NickLaMarca Why do you not like `string moomoo = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MSQueue"];`? What are you trying to accomplish with your `LocalConstants` class?

Comment: Requirement is no magic strings or ConfigurationManager references in code. Wanted all in 1 file. I just took all the strings in the ConfigurationManager and directly put them in the LocalConstants class and it still throwing an exception and returning null

Comment: The type initializer for 'TestCodeOutOnSide.LocalConstants' threw an exception.

Comment: @NickLaMarca Those strings are not _Magic_, they name things you are using, like a CONNECTION_STRING, and what have you.  How is having your own file any different from using the existing `ConfigurationManager`?  And what does "strings in the ConfigurationManager **and directly put them in the LocalConstants**" mean?

Comment: public static readonly string PROJECT_PATH = @"FORMATNAME:DIRECT=OS:serus-nickl\RMQDEV";

Comment: this is what is in LocalConstants now but same result it throws an exception

Comment: @NickLaMarca So `string moomoo = LocalConstants.PROJECT_PATH;` throws that exception, and the only change to the LocalConstants class is that it now includes the line you show in your comment and not the one show in your question, correct?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11279/discussion-between-joshua-drake-and-nick-lamarca)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't try something like:

```
   public static string ProjectPath 
   { 
       get 
       { 
           return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MSQueue"]; 
       } 
   }
```

Comment: Please provide a description / explanation of the code snippet.

Answer (score -1):

You could try making them `readonly`

```
public static readonly string PROJECT_PATH = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MSQueue"];
```

`readonly` fields can be lazy-loaded