# Null Reference Exception Thrown while using connectionstring inside static classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, connection-string, static-classes

In my projects, I used connection string inside non-static classes, and It works fine. But now I'm developing a project that uses connection string inside static classes. In the code below the Catch block will throw an error as shown below:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

If I comment out this line "Throw" it works fine, but I want to understand what went wrong in my code.

`DataAccess` class:

```
public class DataAccess
{
    static string connstr =  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbSystem2018"].ConnectionString;

    public static object GetSingleAnswer(string sql, List<SqlParameter> PList)
    {
        object obj = null;

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

            if (PList != null)
            {
                foreach (SqlParameter p in PList)
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
            }

            obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw; // THIS LINE THROW THE NullReferenceException Error
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

        return obj;
    }
}
```

The problem is with using static connection string field inside static classes. So, is there any way to solve this issue without using any non static public classes?

Updated:

Please notice the following:

1. I don't want to use non-static methods, my question is how we can fix this using static methods.
2. When we use static field, we initialize it right away:

   ```
   static string v1 = "hello";
   ```

   but why the initialization for the following code throw null before returning the actual connection string?

   ```
   static string connstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbSystem2018"].ConnectionString;
   ```

By the way, the connection string inside the `web.config` is fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: i read this before, but as I mentioned , i don't want to use non static classes. what was explained in the link you sent is using non static classes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the exception and the diagnostic data it provides. The link in my 1st comment explains how to troubleshoot and diagnose those NullReferenceExceptions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing Constants Static Class That References App Settings Config File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606899/accessing-constants-static-class-that-references-app-settings-config-file)

Comment: Please post the Exception. Or better, look what the exception says, which function is running into a null reference

Comment: @GSerg, according to the question, the exception happens inside the try-catch block. No App settings seem to be accessed within the try-catch block.

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense now. First you say the exception happens within the try-catch (which you rethrow in the catch body), now with the edit at the end of your question you say the exception is caused by a code line outside the try-catch body. Which is it?

Comment: elgonzo: if i remove Throw in the catch block , it works fine. Also if I use non static methods, it works fine too.

Comment: @reaz of course it works fine if you catch the exeption and don't do anything with it. Exception is still there though. So, post the Exception.

Comment: Sens: 
'The type initializer for 'BANKING.DataLayer.DataAccess' threw an exception.' 
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @reaz and there's no information about the line/function it was thrown in?

Comment: Sens: I only posted one function so the exact thrown part is :
 GetSingleAnswer() 
 Catch  block 
{
Throw ; // The error thrown here 
}

Comment: @reaz Is this `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbSystem2018"].ConnectionString` static?

Comment: Sens: for some reason i tried to initialize a string field then use it inside a static class it works fine: 
Ex.
static string  v="Test"; // static field is initialized and there were no exception thrown 
public  static class Test()
{
Set(v);
}
Catch (exception)
{
Throw;
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174604/discussion-between-reaz-and-sens).

Comment: Remove the entire catch block, not just the throw statement. Now you can see where the exception is originally thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(null);
if (config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Count > 0)
{
    var connString = config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[nameOfConnectionString].ToString();
    return connString;
}
```

Is copy paste from: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1012286/Read-web-config-Settings

The problem is that you're accessing a config file. Those have to be converted to an object before they are accesible. This is what the code above does.